# Style two inline children under in one div so that the left children takes max width

Tags: html, css, less

I have one div holding on two inline children.
Something like..

```
<div>
    <span> stuff </span>
    <span> more stuff with variable length </span>
<div>
```

I want to make my second child to take whatever width it needs, and then the first child to be 100% - second child width. So that the two children are inline.

Is there a css/less only solution to this?

Comment: What CSS/LESS have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be doable using flex properties, but here is how I have gotten it working using float. Note that I changed the spans to divs - it *might* be possible to do this by setting spans to `display: block`, but I just feel this is cleaner. Also, an important aspect of this is the *order* of the divs; the float comes first, so that the "rest" section can base its content on what remains for it.

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  }

.outer > div {
  height: 100%;
  }

.fill {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
  }

.rest {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="fill">This will use up as much space as it needs to</div>
  <div class="rest">Fill content</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I set display:block to my span, and re-arranged the spans like you had. And it worked. I would prefer to not rearrange the spans tho..

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
span {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
span:first-child {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span> stuff </span>
  <span> more stuff with variable length </span>
</div>

<div>
  <span> stuff </span>
  <span> lots and lots of more stuff with variable length </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/123/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span class="span-1"> stuff </span>
    <span class="span-2"> more stuff with variable length </span>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: table;
}
span {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.span-1 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```